# Get selected Item of checkboxlist not coming

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass value to the parameter TYPE 1. How can I do this?

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ConnectionString;
    string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_expense_info";

    int count = 1;
    List<OracleParameter> parameters = new List<OracleParameter>();
    List<string> conditions = new List<string>();

    foreach (ListItem li in ddlStatus.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected)
        {
            conditions.Add(string.Format(":TYPE{0}", count));

            //OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter(string.Format(":TYPE{0}"), OracleType.VarChar);
            OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter(string.Format(":TYPE{0}", count), OracleType.NVarChar);
            p.Value = li.Value;
            parameters.Add(p);
            count++;
        }
    }

    string whereCondition = string.Empty;
    if (conditions.Count > 0)
    {
        whereCondition = " Where type IN (" + string.Join(",", conditions) + ")";
    }

    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(constr))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strQuery + whereCondition))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":TYPE", OracleType.VarChar) = what to pass here?

            using (OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                using (DataTable dtcheck = new DataTable())
                {
                    oda.Fill(dtcheck);
                    GridExpInfo.DataSource = dtcheck;
                    GridExpInfo.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem in your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to loop through, to see if it is selected.  The value can be retrieved in a couple of approaches:

```
var value = dropdown.SelectedValue;
var text = dropdown.SelectedItem.Text;
```

More detail can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx).